# Angular 8 multiple validators not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

> 

I have a reactive form control and it has more than 1 validator. I defined it as the below methods and none of it's not actually validating it. below is the code which I tried.

**1 method**

```
civilIdNumber: new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12), Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")])),
```

**2 method**

```
civilIdNumber: new FormControl("",[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12), Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")])
```

**Html Code**

```
<form [formGroup]="customerForm">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="civil">Civil ID Number</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Civil ID Number"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="civil"
                  formControlName="civilIdNumber"
                  required
                  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': customerForm.controls.civilIdNumber.invalid && customerForm.controls.civilIdNumber.touched }"
                />

                <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].invalid && (customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].dirty || customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].touched)" class="text-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].errors.required">Civil ID Number required</div>
                </div>
              </div>
     </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: And what is the question/problem?

Comment: Can we see the initial setup of your customerForm please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should also _really_ [update your Angular](https://angular.io/cli/update) to the latest available version (currently 12). Angular 8 has been out of support for years. https://angular.io/guide/releases

Comment: I can not remember if in Angular 8 you should use `customerForm.get('...')` in stead of customer.controls["'...'] -in general the suggest is use always the way "myForm.get(nameOfcontrol)". The only you only see the error if required, you should put as many error as you need, e.g. for minLength is `<div *ngIf="customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].errors.minLength"`>Min length error</div>`. Note use a {{customerForm.get('civilIdNumber')?.errors |json}} to know about what do you ask

Answer (score 2):

In your .ts

```
customerForm: FormGroup;
constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
   {
    civilIdNumber: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12), 
    Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")] ]
   }
)
}
```

In your .html

```
<div class="col-sm-6" [formGroup]="customerForm"> <!-- this makes it work -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="civil">Civil ID Number</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Civil ID Number"
              class="form-control"
              id="civil"
              formControlName="civilIdNumber"
              required
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': customerForm.get('civilIdNumber').invalid && customerForm.get('civilIdNumber').touched }"
            />

            <div *ngIf="customerForm.get('civilIdNumber').invalid && (customerForm.get('civilIdNumber').dirty || customerForm.get('civilIdNumber').touched)" class="text-danger">
              <div *ngIf="customerForm.get('civilIdNumber').errors.required">Civil ID Number required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding your control properly. Form control name makes sense only in context of `formGroup` parent (or formArray but lest skip that)

```
<div class="col-sm-6" [formGroup]="customerForm"> <!-- this makes it work -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="civil">Civil ID Number</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Civil ID Number"
              class="form-control"
              id="civil"
              formControlName="civilIdNumber"
              required
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': customerForm.controls.civilIdNumber.invalid && customerForm.controls.civilIdNumber.touched }"
            />

            <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].invalid && (customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].dirty || customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].touched)" class="text-danger">
              <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls['civilIdNumber'].errors.required">Civil ID Number required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this does not help, reproduce on stackblitz.

Comment: I already did that my Html is lengthy that's why I put like this

Comment: Reproduce on stackblitz